# ng-class not being applied when using setValidation()

Tags: angularjs, validation, ng-class

I have a login form that has required and email validation. If either of these validations fail, the error message is displayed and the error class is applied to the field.

These are applied as expected. When the user logs in, if the credentials fail, I want to manually add a validation error. This invalidates the form, and my message is displayed saying 'Email/password combination is not recognised', but the error class is not applied to the field - even though (loginForm.$submitted && !loginForm.email.$valid) evaluates to true.

What am I missing here?

js:

```
login() {
  if (!this.$scope.loginForm.$valid) {
    return;
  }

  this.authenticationService
    .login(this.email, this.password)
    .success((response) => {
      //success code...
    })
    .error((response) => {
      if (response.error === 'invalid_grant') {
        this.$timeout(() => {
          this.$scope.$apply(() => {
            this.$scope.loginForm.email.$setValidity('invalidGrant', false);
          });
        });
      }
    });
}
```

html:

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="loginController.login()" novalidate>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="loginController.email" required=""
        ng-class="{error:loginForm.$submitted && !loginForm.email.$valid}" />
    <div ng-show="loginForm.$submitted">
        <span ng-show="loginForm.email.$error.required">Email field is required.</span>
        <span ng-show="loginForm.email.$error.email">Email field is not valid.</span>
        <span ng-show="loginForm.email.$error.invalidGrant">Email/password combination is not recognised.</span>
    </div>
<!-- other fields... -->
<button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think `error` needs to be in single quotes

Comment: @Ronnie cheers but tried that, no luck. It works fine for required and email validation.

Comment: you wrapped single quotes around `error` in `ng-class` right? Could you try a different format of ng-class for me? `ng-class="loginForm.$submitted && !loginForm.email.$valid ? 'error' : ''"`